# iphone - UITableView doesn't scroll after Xcode 4.5 update

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

My app has number of `UITableViews` embedded into `NavigationController`. After I updated to Xcode 4.5 GM one of tables has stopped scrolling. There are no any other views on top of it.
Any ideas on what might be wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

There are two gesture recognisers on my tableView to recognise swipes left/right. If I remove them - tableview is scrolling...

Comment: Isn't 4.5 still covered by the NDA? You might not get a good answer here until next week...

Comment: Genericly, for a scrollView to scroll it needs to be configured with a contentSize that is > than the view size. Did you verify this by logging these values (including the scrolling enabled flag) in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes. Content size is much bigger than a view size and scrollEnabled = YES

Comment: Have you compared the settings to other tableviews, that are scrolling ok?

Comment: Have just tried old versions of my project, which were 100% working - the same thing. UITableView doesn't scroll

Comment: ... and when built with Xcode 4.4, works like a charm, right? If so, I ran into the same problem couple of months ago, submitted bug report only to find it closed with "Behaves correctly". Sigh.

Comment: yes, right! I've managed to solve this issue by adding gesture recognizers programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Xcode 4.5
After adding gesture recognizers programatically everything should work perfectly!